# ef core unit test echec

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I have a method in my repository that I’m trying to test

```cs
public User UpdateUserManyToMany(User user, List<Guid> manyToManyds)
{
    var dbContext = _databaseContext as DbContext;

    dbContext?.TryUpdateManyToMany(user.ManyToMany, manyToManyds
        .Select(x => new ManyToMany{
            OtherEntityId = x,
            UserId = user.Id,
        }), x => x.OtherEntityId);

    return user;
}
```

My ManyToMany Entity :

```cs
public class ManyToMany 
{
        public Guid OtherEntityId { get; set; }

        public OtherEntity OtherEntityId { get; set; }

        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
}
```

My TryUpdateManyToMany :

```cs
public static class ManyToManyExtensions
{
    public static void TryUpdateManyToMany<T, TKey>(this DbContext db, IEnumerable<T> currentItems, IEnumerable<T> newItems, Func<T, TKey> getKey) where T : class
    {
        db.Set<T>().RemoveRange(currentItems.Except(newItems, getKey));
        db.Set<T>().AddRange(newItems.Except(currentItems, getKey));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other, Func<T, TKey> getKeyFunc)
    {
        return items
            .GroupJoin(other, getKeyFunc, getKeyFunc, (item, tempItems) => new { item, tempItems })
            .SelectMany(t => t.tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty(), (t, temp) => new { t, temp })
            .Where(t => ReferenceEquals(null, t.temp) || t.temp.Equals(default(T)))
            .Select(t => t.t.item);
    }
}
```

Here’s my unit test :

```cs
using (var context = new InMemoryDataBaseContext())
{
    // Arrange
    var repository = new UserRepository(context);
    await context.Users.AddRangeAsync(GetUser());
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Act
    var manyIds = new List<Guid>();
    manyIds.Add(Guid.Parse("855d1a64-a707-40d5-ab93-34591a923abf"));
    manyIds.Add(Guid.Parse("855d1a64-a787-40d9-ac93-34591a923abf"));
    manyIds.Add(Guid.Parse("855d1a64-a707-41d9-ab93-39591a923abf"));

    var user = new User();
    var expected = repository.UpdateUserManyToMany(GetUser(), manyIds);

    // Assert
}
```

But I get the following error in my test :

````
 Message: 
    System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity type 'ManyToMany' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'UserId', 'OtherEntityId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.
  Arborescence des appels de procédure: 
    IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)
    IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
    IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry)
    NullableKeyIdentityMap`1.Add(InternalEntityEntry entry)
    StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
    InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)
    InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
    EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node)
    EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode`1 node, Func`2 handleNode)
    EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState targetState, EntityState storeGeneratedWithKeySetTargetState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
    DbContext.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
    DbContext.RemoveRange(IEnumerable`1 entities)
    InternalDbSet`1.RemoveRange(IEnumerable`1 entities)
    ManyToManyExtensions.TryUpdateManyToMany[T,TKey](DbContext db, IEnumerable`1 currentItems, IEnumerable`1 newItems, Func`2 getKey) ligne 24
    UserRepository.UpdateUserManyToMany(User user, List`1 manyToManyds) ligne 59
    MyRepoUnitTest.MyTestMethod() ligne 102
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ```
````

Comment: Please post the `ManyToMany` class (and corresponding Fluent API if any), the code for the `DbContext.TryUpdateManyToMany()` extension method and the _full_ stack trace.

Comment: I'm update my answer

Comment: You do everything with one context instance.

Comment: What is  the problem ? My method work in prod but not working in unit test

Comment: *This* code doesn't run in production. It's a test artifact.

Comment: My Updateusermanytomany method works in production but does not work in a unit test

Comment: In production you're not adding a user and updating it using one and the same context. This is a typical unit test gotcha.

Comment: Okay, but here’s how I do my unit test

Comment: Can we agree that a unit test should reflect real-life use cases? So how would you mimic a realistic update of an existing user in a unit test? Not by using the same context for the update.

Comment: What is the solution please

Answer (score 0):

The following sample program, that is based on the code you provided, works without issues:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<ManyToMany> ManyToMany { get; set; } = new HashSet<ManyToMany>();
    }

    public class OtherEntity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<ManyToMany> ManyToMany { get; set; } = new HashSet<ManyToMany>();
    }

    public class ManyToMany 
    {
        public Guid OtherEntityId { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public OtherEntity OtherEntity { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<OtherEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ManyToMany> ManyToMany { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So63077461")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<OtherEntity>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

                    entity.HasMany(e => e.ManyToMany)
                        .WithOne(e => e.OtherEntity)
                        .HasForeignKey(e => e.OtherEntityId);

                    entity.HasData(
                        new OtherEntity
                        {
                            Id = new Guid("855d1a64-a707-40d5-ab93-34591a923abf"),
                            Name = "Bicycle"
                        },
                        new OtherEntity
                        {
                            Id = new Guid("855d1a64-a787-40d9-ac93-34591a923abf"),
                            Name = "Bus"
                        },
                        new OtherEntity
                        {
                            Id = new Guid("855d1a64-a707-41d9-ab93-39591a923abf"),
                            Name = "Plane"
                        });
                });
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);

                    entity.HasMany(e => e.ManyToMany)
                        .WithOne(e => e.User)
                        .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);
                });
            modelBuilder.Entity<ManyToMany>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasKey(e => new {e.OtherEntityId, e.UserId});
                });
        }
    }

    public static class ManyToManyExtensions
    {
        public static void TryUpdateManyToMany<T, TKey>(this DbContext db, IEnumerable<T> currentItems, IEnumerable<T> newItems, Func<T, TKey> getKey) where T : class
        {
            db.Set<T>().RemoveRange(currentItems.Except(newItems, getKey));
            db.Set<T>().AddRange(newItems.Except(currentItems, getKey));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> Except<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, IEnumerable<T> other, Func<T, TKey> getKeyFunc)
        {
            return items
                .GroupJoin(other, getKeyFunc, getKeyFunc, (item, tempItems) => new { item, tempItems })
                .SelectMany(t => t.tempItems.DefaultIfEmpty(), (t, temp) => new { t, temp })
                .Where(t => ReferenceEquals(null, t.temp) || t.temp.Equals(default(T)))
                .Select(t => t.t.item);
        }
    }

    internal class UserRepository
    {
        private readonly Context _databaseContext;

        public UserRepository(Context context)
        {
            _databaseContext = context;
        }
        
        public User UpdateUserManyToMany(User user, List<Guid> manyToManyds)
        {
            var dbContext = _databaseContext as DbContext;

            dbContext?.TryUpdateManyToMany(user.ManyToMany, manyToManyds
                .Select(x => new ManyToMany{
                    OtherEntityId = x,
                    UserId = user.Id,
                }), x => x.OtherEntityId);

            return user;
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main()
        {
            //
            // Operations with referential integrity intact:
            //
            
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            // Arrange
            var repository = new UserRepository(context);
            await context.Users.AddRangeAsync(GetUser());
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Act
            var manyIds = new List<Guid>
            {
                new Guid("855d1a64-a707-40d5-ab93-34591a923abf"),
                new Guid("855d1a64-a787-40d9-ac93-34591a923abf"),
                new Guid("855d1a64-a707-41d9-ab93-39591a923abf")
            };

            var expected = repository.UpdateUserManyToMany(GetUser(), manyIds);
        }

        private static User GetUser()
            => User;

        private static readonly User User = new User
        {
            Id = new Guid("30c35d2e-77fd-480b-9974-6ebf037a8f86"),
            Name = "John"
        };
    }
}
```

> System.InvalidOperationException : The instance of entity type 'ManyToMany' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'UserId', 'OtherEntityId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

The error message says, that at least one of your `ManyToMany` entries already exists in the database (there is an entry with the same `UserId` and `OtherEntityId` combination).

You can verify this, by running the following code directly after your filled the `manyIds` variable with the 3 IDs:

```cs
var user = GetUser();
var alreadyExistingManyToMany = context.ManyToMany
    .Where(m => m.UserId == user.Id &&
                manyIds.Contains(m.OtherEntityId))
    .ToList();

Debug.Assert(alreadyExistingManyToMany.Count == 0);
```

Comment: I don’t see any difference with what I have as a code. The method works well in production. It’s just when I call it in my unit tests that it doesn’t work

Comment: That is my point. The code generally works as is. But there already seems to exist at least one `ManyToMany` entry in the table of your test database, that is identical to what you try to insert, which then leads to the exception being thrown (because there can be only one primary key with the same value at a time in a given table). Use the second code snippet I posted to find out what `ManyToMany` entities already exist and are going to throw an exception later in `TryUpdateManyToMany`.

Comment: I don’t understand. The method adds the key only if it does not exist in theory. It would be said that this does not work in unit testing while it works in prod

Comment: Just enable EF Core logging, so the actual SQL queries get logged. Then manually run the generated query that fails manually against the database (in SSMS or so).

Comment: Clearly you are telling me that I cannot test my method individually. Plus I use a database in memory for my test

Comment: Did you add the second code snipped of my answer? Does it return any entities in its `alreadyExistingManyToMany ` variable? Also, enabling EF Core logging will always work. So enable it and add the failing query to your question, so we can take a look at it.